# CSS - Search Results - Image , title and description

Tags: html, css, layout

Can anyone show me how to do a simple CSS layout for some search results that show

An Image on the left hand side
And to the right of that, a title with text underneath

Have been messing around with floats but not having any joy

```
<div id="" class="searchResult">
    <div class="resultIcon">
        <img class="icon" src="/placeholder.png" width="42" height="42"/>
    </div>
    <div class="optionText">
        <p class="Heading" >
            This is the title of the result
        </p>
        <p>This is a load of text describing the result. It's just a summary blah, It's just a summary blah</>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.searchResult, .optionText { overflow: hidden }
.resultIcon { float: left; margin-right: 10px }
```